# pylint prints warning about missing module docstring while it has

Tags: python, pylint, docstring

The first lines of multisql.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Execute SQL on multiple servers
"""
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import os
...
```

pylint warning:

```
[mutex@thinkpad multisql] @  $ pylint *.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module setup
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

According to the "Module setup" in that output, that message is because there isn't a docstring in your `setup.py`, not `multisql.py`.

Comment: @pensnarik Please provide the checkmark if that answered your question. I just landed here with the same problem.